# Version 7.13.0 Bixby IDE update. Action .js scripts appearing as normal text?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I have updated the Bixby IDE today to the most recent update: **Version 7.13.0**. I was wondering if it is normal for the .js action scripts to appear without theme and color?

Thank you.

Comment: That didn't answer the question.

Comment: If you think you are running into a bug, feel free to use the "Contact Support" menu item in the Bixby Studio to reach us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for letting us know.

A hot fix has been deployed by IDE group. I've verified the fix myself.

Version (7.13.0-r20d.15375) would fix this issue. Please restart IDE and follow the prompt to download/install new version.

Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for letting us know this issue so quickly. Wish you have some fun developing with Bixby.